# Disable (dot)php files from being executed (NGINX+PHP)

Tags: nginx, php, wordpress

**Question** 
I am wondering if my configuration was executing the hacked dot files before removal.

**Setup**
Ubuntu 18.04 LTS + NGINX + PHP 7.4

**Issue**
My Wordpress site got hacked. The malware created a copy of each file and named it `.{filename}` (mention the dot in front).

This is what the hacked directory looks like:
`index.php (normal)`
`.index.php (hacked, being executed I guess)`

This is what my vhost looks like:

```
# Deny access to hidden files
  location ~ /\. {
      deny all;
  }
  location ~* /(?:uploads|files)/.*\.php\$ {
    deny all;
  }
  location ~ ^/wp-includes/[^/]+\.php\$ {
      deny all;
  }
```

(*) I did not made any adjustments to the standard php.ini, except raising the max_execution_time and some other limits.

Do you think this was enough to prevent PHP of executing these hacked files?

**Wordpress fix**
This command automatically removes all dot php files from the /var/www directory:
`find /var/www/-type f -name .\*.php # -delete # UNCOMMENT to actually delete`

After that, I have deleted and manually downloaded new copies in /wp-content/plugins, /wp-content/themes, /wp-includes, /wp-admin and restored a back-up of /wp-content/uploads and /wp-content/languages. So yes, I think my Wordpress site is clean now.

Comment: Where are those lines relative to other *regular expression* `location` blocks? *Regular expression* `location` blocks are evaluated in order until a match is found, so `location ~ /\.` needs to be first if it is to be effective.

Comment: Great suggestion. By default, I have set the php-fpm block at the bottom of the NGINX file so other rules are executed first.